# change footline box position

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using theme "goettingen" to build my beamer presentation. I have used the following settings for my slides

```
\usetheme[hideothersubsections, left, width=.15\paperwidth]{goettingen}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}

\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue!15}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth, center]{date in head/foot}
\insertshortdate\hfill\insertshortinstitute\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\vskip0pt
\end{beamercolorbox}

}
```

However I am not able to locate the footline box to the right. I hope the following shot clarifies my question.
Also I want to configure the default buttons that comes with the theme. I hope someone has idea how to configure it as shown in the following shot.

[image]

I will be grateful if someone has idea also to control color of the footline box to be degraded like the left bar

Answer (score 1):

Try `\hfill` or `\hfil` just before the beamercolorbox.  This will push the box to the right.

```
\setbeamertemaple{footline}
{\hfill
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth, center]{date in head/foot}
  \insertshortdate\hfill\insertshortinstitute\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\vskip0pt
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
```